# create boost libraries from source code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I am using boost in a project and I want to create a librarie which include the boost interprocess librarie that I use in my project. 
I have got, using the boost tool bcp, the interprocess sources separate from all the boost code, But what I want to create a lib from that sources. Or maybe somebody know how to create a .lib from Boost libraries.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to know how to build boost library or you want to make your application to be made a static or shared library ??

Comment: I want to make my application to be made a static librarie, but including boost so the next application that uses my librarie does not have to include boost

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the bcp tool, it is used to extract a subset of the sources from the boost tree. I'm not sure if the extracted sources can be built using bjam, but have you tried?

On how to build boost, simply have a look at their [Getting Started Guide For Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source

You do not build boost libraries directly from Visual Studio, but rather use the `bjam` tool that will invoke Visual Studio for you to generate the binaries.

Oh, and regarding Boost.Interprocess:

> There is no need to compile
>   Boost.Interprocess, since it's a
>   header only library. Just include your
>   Boost header directory in your
>   compiler include path.

You cannot create a lib for Boost.Interprocess, because it is a header-only library.

Comment: Hi, I have built boost, but you do not get the different ".libs" for the different libraries, for example interprocess, or maybe I did it wrong... I have tried bjam but it does not generate a lib...I have built the vcproj of the librarie "_interprocessslib.vcpoj", and it builds (too fast I think), and it is a librarian... but no .lib is generated...Any suggestion?

Comment: Libs *are* generated, but B.IP is a header only lib!

Comment: sorry Martin, is the first time I have seen B.IP...I do not know how this is related to my problem...although the librarie I want to build would only contain headers

Comment: B.IP == Boost.InterProcess for lazy-typers like me. | You cannot build a library that consists of headers. Libraries (.lib, .dll) are for implementation files (.c, .cpp, .cc).

Comment: So the only option is to add boost interprocess, as Additional Include Libraries in Visual Studio, in every project which use my project become in library (which contains has as additional libaries boost)?

Comment: @david: Yes, that would be my preferred way, to add the boost tree (however suitably reduced) to the *project* settings as additional library directory.